# Material ui: Как динамически менять свойства массива иконок?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icon, material-ui

Есть большой массив иконок, условно:

```
const ICONS_ARRAY: React.ReactNode[] = [
<AlertCircleCheckOutline />,
<AppleSafari />,
<MotionPlay />,
<AppleKeyboardCommand />,
<FileDocumentMultipleOutline />,
<ClipboardArrowLeftOutline />,
<ViewDashboardOutline />,
<CalendarClockOutline />,
<RobotHappyOutline />,
<AccountWrenchOutline />,
<AccountGroupOutline />,
<AccountCogOutline />,
<RunFast />,
<SpeedometerSlow />]
```

Они выводятся в выпадающем списке.
Нужно всем им присвоить свойства (размер, цвет),желательно без инлайн стилей и,что важно,мы используем mu v4.

Были попытки сделать так (i - индекс элемента в массиве):

```
               <MenuItem>
                    <Box>
                        <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}>ICONS_ARRAY[i]</SvgIcon>
                    </Box>
                </MenuItem>,
```

Не работает (выводится белый прямоугольник без иконки). Зато если вместо ICONS_ARRAY[i] подставить непосредственно сам компонент,то все работает:

```
               <MenuItem>
                    <Box>
                        <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}><RunFast /></SvgIcon>
                    </Box>
                </MenuItem>
```

Аналогично происходит при попытке присвоить свойства через React.cloneElement.

Подскажите пожалуйста рабочий метод или в чем ошибка. Не хочется в каждый элемент руками копировать свойства...

Answer (score 0):

Ответ такой - иногда надо отдыхать)) Просто не хватало скобок

```
  <MenuItem>
        <Box>
            <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}>{ICONS_ARRAY[i]}</SvgIcon>
        </Box>
    </MenuItem>
```